# passing javascript value into form action

Tags: javascript

I have the form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="test.php?date=javascript:this.form.date2.value">
```

I am using a DatetimePicker for PHP like below:

```
        $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date2");
        $myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
        $myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));
        $myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
        $myCalendar->setYearInterval(1970, 2020);
        $myCalendar->dateAllow('2008-05-13', '2015-03-01', false);
        $myCalendar->startMonday(true);
        $myCalendar->autoSubmit(true, "form1", "test.php");
        $myCalendar->autoSubmit(true, "form1");
        $myCalendar->showWeeks(true);  
        $myCalendar->writeScript();
```

The thing is i cannot pass the date value from datetimepicker into form action where the url is "test.php?=date="

How would this be possible to pass the value of datetimepicker by just clicking on calendar, not using any extra button and using onsubmit event.

After execution the result in URL looks like this:
test.php?date=javascript:this.form.date2.value

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need javascript to submit a form without ajax.
As you want to sent GET variables with ? sign, jsut use GET method in your form and set the name of the input to the name of the variable you want to get sent. (if you can replace 'date2' with 'date'):

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="test.php">
    <input name='date' />
```

Comment: in the action why dont u use ? after test.php, how will i pass a value to it differently?
and i cannot get to pass a value to <input name='date'> :S

Comment: This is how html forms work with the GET method. The browser directs you to a rewritten url like "yourdomain.com/script.php?formfield1name=formfield1value&formfield2name=formfield2value..."

Comment: hey Armel L. I should accept your answer since the problem was at method="get"  before i had method="post" thats why didnt work :d. now it works but my url is a litle bit longer for ex like this:

test/calendar/test.php?date=2012-09-14&date_dp=&date_year_start=1970&date_year_end=2015&date_da1=1210629600&date_da2=1425164400&date_sna... how do i remove the rest after the ?date=2012-09-14 ???

Comment: You could just leave it like that... See Datepicker Calendar php library's documentation if there is any... You might be able to configurate it so it outputs only one field...